# Rails ActiveAdmin form for many-to-many relationship through a join table not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, many-to-many, schema, activeadmin

I have in my Rails application BlogPosts and BlogCategories, and a BlogPostCategorization table to join them together. So

```
class BlogCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :created_at, :updated_at, :blog_post_id
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  has_many :blog_post_categorizations
  has_many :blog_posts, :through => :blog_post_categorizations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :blog_posts, allow_destroy: true
end
class BlogPost < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :body, :created_at, :updated_at, :image_url, :title
  validates :body, :image_url, :title, presence: true
  validates :title, uniqueness: true
  has_many :blog_post_categorizations
  has_many :blog_categories, :through => :blog_post_categorizations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :blog_categories, allow_destroy: true
end
class BlogPostCategorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :blog_post
  belongs_to :blog_category
end
```

Now through ActiveAdmin, I want to be able to create a new blog post, and create categories for this blog post. I have

```
form do |f|
    f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys
    f.inputs "Blog Post" do
      f.input :title
      f.input :body, as: :html_editor
      f.input :image_url
    end
    f.inputs "Blog Categories" do
      f.has_many :blog_post_categorizations do |s|
        s.input :blog_category
      end
    end
    f.actions
end
```

But when I try to access the active admin page for new Blog Post, I get a rails error message saying "undefined method `new_record?' for nil:NilClass" on the line where

f.has_many :blog_post_categorizations do |s|

What am I doing wrong/missing?

Additionally, included below is the blog_category data that's being sent in the params hash of the POST request

```
"blog_categories_attributes"=>{"1408936652467"=>{"name"=>"cooking"}, "1408936656066"=>{"name"=>"eat"}}
```

Comment: what version of Rails do you use?

Comment: I'm using Rails 3.2.17

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this part:

```
f.inputs "Blog Categories" do
  f.has_many :blog_post_categorizations do |s|
    s.input :blog_category
  end
end
```

should be:

```
f.inputs "Blog Categories" do
  f.has_many :blog_categorys do |s|
    s.input :name
  end
end
```

---

### **EDIT**

Taking into account your another question on this issue I would recommend a (I hope) good workaround. Since [strong_parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) are by default used in Rails 4 and higher, and you are on Rails 3.2.17, let us make your app use it.
So there are the steps:

- install `gem 'strong_parameters'`;
- set to false `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes` in `config/application.rb`;
- `include ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection` in the `BlogPost` and `BlogCategory` models;
- get rid of all `attr_accessible` calls.

Having all this done you can whitelist all params in private method, like so:

```
private

def blog_post_params
  params.require(:blog_post).permit(#all the params here)
end
```

And in #create action use `BlogPost.new(blog_post_params)` (same in other model(s), where you use the included module). Now you can benefit from strong_parameters.

In ActiveAdmin `BlogPost` model whitelist all permitted parameters as:

```
permit_params :body, :created_at, :updated_at, :image_url, :title, blog_categories_attributes: [:id, :name, :_destroy, :blog_post_id]
```

and in controller

```
controller do 
  def permitted_params 
    params.permit blog_posts: [:body, :created_at, :updated_at, :image_url, :title, blog_categories_attributes: [:id, :name, :_destroy, :blog_post_id]]
  end 
end
```

Take a more precise look at strong_params usage in documentation. And also double check typos/wrong namings/underscores (because I presumed some things).

Good luck!

Comment: That change makes it so the new BlogPost page will load, but when I try to submit the new post with a couple added categories, I get a cannot mass-assign attributes error for blogcategories

Comment: it means we have fixed the initial problem (hoorey!) but there is a new problem. And that is you have to whitelist the id attribute of nested model. So that add :id to attr_accessible (this is how it works in rails 4, hoping the same in 3.2.17..) to blogcategory model

Comment: And I've made sure to include every field under attr_accessible

Comment: hey, how's the going with that? haven't been online for a while.. If you still facing the same error, try adding permitted params method to activeadmin (also try to include everything as permitted, including :id). Like this   controller do
    #...
    def permitted_params
      params.permit(:blogposts => [:name, :description])
    end
  end

Comment: I'm using Rails 3.2 and I believe permitted_params is for Rails 4

Comment: maybe try config.before_filter do
  params.permit!
end in config/initializers/active_admin.rb? Btw, in for the sake of forum rules you can accept the answer (taking into account the fact, that the initial issue was eliminated) even though it is still throwing some error..

Comment: config.before_filter do
    params.permit!
  end also does not work

Comment: Where am I supposed to use the private method blog_post_params?

Comment: I tried all the steps, and with that clause under the controller method in the active_admin model for some reason adding a new post doesn't throw a failure, but redirects to the new blog page with every field highlighted saying "Field must not be empty". Btw, this is in a project with 20+ models which all rely on attr_accessible, so I don't think using strong_params is a viable option for this specific model

Comment: One thing I'm thinking is, in the params hash, "blog_categories_attributes"=>{"1408936652467"=>{"name"=>"cooking"}, "1408936656066"=>{"name"=>"eat"}}, where does the 1408936652467 come from? I don't have any categories, nevermind that many for that to be the UID. Maybe that's somehow incorrectly being generated and not mapping to the schema? Is there a way I can through ruby console attempt to construct a BlogPost object off a raw params hash and do trial and error till I can find a schema it works with?

Comment: don't really know where the numbers come from.. Why you say you don't have categories?

Comment: At the time I had no categories in the DB, and this was the params hash of the first attempt to create any

Comment: This didn't fix the solution but I'll give you the bounty because you've been very helpful...

Comment: Thank you! I really wanted to help, pity that you still do not have the solution..

Comment: Yeah thanks, any idea here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25614802/rails-activeadmin-carrierwave-has-many-photos-relationship-throwing-mass-assignm