# Rails activeadmin/carrierwave has_many photos relationship throwing mass-assignment exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activeadmin, carrierwave, mass-assignment

I have a model BlogPost defined as

```
class BlogPost < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :title, :body, :photo, :photos_attributes, as: :admin
  has_many :photos, class_name: 'BlogPhoto', dependent: :destroy
  validates :body, :photo, :title, presence: true
  validates :title, uniqueness: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos, allow_destroy: true
end
```

from schema

```
create_table "blog_posts", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "body"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.string   "photo"
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
end
class BlogPhoto < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :blog_post
  attr_accessible :photo, as: :admin

  mount_uploader :photo, BlogPhotoUploader
end
```

and an activeadmin form to create a new blogpost

```
form do |f|
    f.inputs "Blog Post" do
      f.input :title
      f.input :body, as: :html_editor
    end
    f.inputs "Photos" do
      f.has_many :photos do |p|
        p.input :photo, as: :file
        p.input :_destroy, as: :boolean, required: false, label: 'Remove Photo'
      end
    end
    f.actions
 end
```

I am also using carrierwave to upload photos to S3. With all of thise code, when I try to create a new blogpost inside of active admin, I get a mass-assignment error saying:
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: title, body, photos_attributes

However, you can see I've very clearly white-listed those attributes, so what could be causing this?

EDIT: Included following line to

```
class BlogPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :photo, BlogPhotoUploader
```

and now the exception is

```
undefined method `validate_integrity' for :BlogImageUploader:Symbol
```

Comment: have you tried this?  mount_uploader :profile_image, :ImageUploader, :options => {:ignore__integrity_errors => true}

Comment: For some reason now, even the presence of that statement is causing this error to be thrown undefined method `validate_integrity' for :BlogImageUploader:Symbol. It'll even cause a fatal error loading a completely different resource view

Comment: It'll also throw a fatal error when trying to start up the rails server

Comment: don't know what to say. Truth is that I have started learning rails starting from 4, and you are working with rails 3.2. And it is strange  you often have attributes accessibility problems..